# Simple implementation of nxn Dense Matrix in Java

Tags: java, object-oriented, matrix

So far this is what I have completed. Still working on these two methods

- boolean isIdentityMatrix(DenseMatrix matrix);
- boolean isInvertible(DenseMatrix matrix);

Suggestions are appreciated. Thanks.

**//Dense Matrix**

```
package matrix.denseMatrix;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class DenseMatrix
{
    private int[][] elements;
    private int n;

    // in default 3x3 matrix will be created
    public DenseMatrix()
    {
        this(3);
    }

    public DenseMatrix(int size)
    {
        n = size;
        elements = new int[n][n];

        for(int[] rows : elements)
        {
            Arrays.fill(rows, 0);
        }
    }

    public int size()
    {
        return n;
    }

    public int getValue(int i, int j)
    {
        if((i | j) >= n || (i | j) < 0)
        {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        }
        else
        {
            return elements[i][j];
        }
    }

    public boolean set(int i, int j, int value)
    {
        if((i | j) >= n || (i | j) < 0)
        {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        }
        else
        {
            elements[i][j] = value;
            return true;
        }
    }

    public boolean increaseBy(int i, int j, int valueBy) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException
    {
        return set(i, j, getValue(i, j) + valueBy);
    }

    public boolean decreaseBy(int i, int j, int valueBy) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException
    {
        return set(i, j, getValue(i, j) - valueBy);
    }

    public void clear()
    {
        elements = null;
        n = 0;
    }

    public DenseMatrix add(DenseMatrix other)
    {
        if(this.size() != other.size())
        {
            return null;
        }
        else
        {
            DenseMatrix result = new DenseMatrix(this.size());

            for(int i = 0; i < this.size(); i++)
            {
                for(int j = 0; j < this.size(); j++)
                {
                    result.set(i, j, this.getValue(i, j) + other.getValue(i, j));
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
       }

    public DenseMatrix negative()
    {
        DenseMatrix result = new DenseMatrix(this.size());

        for(int i = 0; i < this.size(); i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < this.size(); j++)
            {
                result.set(i, j, this.getValue(i, j) * -1);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    public DenseMatrix multiply(DenseMatrix other)
    {
        if(this.size() != other.size())
        {
            return null;
        }
        else
        {
            DenseMatrix result = new DenseMatrix(this.size());

            for(int i = 0; i < this.size(); i++)
            {
                for(int j = 0; j < this.size(); j++)
                {
                    for(int k = 0; k < this.size(); k++)
                    {
                        result.increaseBy(i, j, (this.getValue(i, k) * other.getValue(k, j)));
                    }
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
    }

    public DenseMatrix transpose()
    {
        DenseMatrix result = new DenseMatrix(this.size());

        for(int i = 0; i < this.size(); i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < this.size(); j++)
            {
                result.set(i, j, this.getValue(j, i));
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object)
    {
        if (this == object)
        {
            return true;
        }
        if (!(object instanceof DenseMatrix))
        {
            return false;
        }

        DenseMatrix that = (DenseMatrix) object;

        if(this.size() != that.size())
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            boolean isEqual = true;
            CHECKING: for(int i = 0; i < this.size(); i++)
            {
                for(int j = 0; j < this.size(); j++)
                {
                    if(this.getValue(i, j) != that.getValue(i, j))
                    {
                        isEqual = false;
                        break CHECKING;
                    }
                }
            }
            return isEqual;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public DenseMatrix clone()
    {
        DenseMatrix clonedMatrix = new DenseMatrix(this.size());

        for(int i = 0; i < this.size(); i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < this.size(); j++)
            {
                clonedMatrix.set(i, j, this.getValue(i, j));
            }
        }
        return clonedMatrix;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if((i | j) >= n || (i | j) < 0)
```

This line does not work as you probably expect:
`i | j` is the binary `or` function and will create a new int, like in this example:

```
i = 0101_b;
j = 0011_b;
k = i | j; // == 0111_b
```

You will get false IndexOutOfBoundsException with this, for example, if your matrix is 3x3, and you call `getValue(2, 1)`.

Comment: A 2x2 matrix can have the max index of (1, 1). Any index being above 1 will throw IndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: I typed the wrong number, sorry. I meant 3x3. You will get IndexOutOfBounds because `2 | 1 = 3`, `3 >= 3 is true` and therefore you will get an IndexOutOfBounds when you have a 3x3 matrix and enter `getValue(2,1)`

Answer (score 2):

**one dimensional array**
Defining the backing array with only one dimension allows immediatly to use the class `Arrays` - instead of row- or column-wise. It provides functionality which then you don't need to write.

`private int[] elements;`

Initialization:
`elements = new int[n*n];`

That's all. There is no need to fill the array row-wise with `0`. According to [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5) all elements are initialized with the default value of the component type. This is `0` in case of `int`,

Determine the position of an element to get or set it's value: `elements[i * n + j];`

**comparing two arrays for equality**
When using a one dimensional array you can call `Arrays.equals(int[] a, int[] b)` to check if the backing arrays are equal.

**cloning the matrix**
When using a one dimensional array you can call `Arrays.copyOf(elements, elements.length)` to create a copy of the backing array using a `native` method which performs very fast.

**dedicated zero-size matrix**
If your application will use frequently zero-size matrices, you could follow the example of `Collections.emptyMap()` and implement a dedicated subtype of `DenseMatrix` which will have simplified implementations of the mathods provided by `DenseMatrix`. Storing such a zero-sized matrix as a singleton will save memory and creation time.